# SSRS one model returns data another does not

Tags: reporting-services, report, datasourceview

I have one report model based on a data source view. I also have a report running a query which returns some data.

I have added a field in the database in some table. I have refreshed only that table in the dsv (by deleting it and adding it back and restoring the thee relations it had, because I did not want to refresh the whole dsv).

I have created a new model based on this new, slightly modified dsv. I have uploaded this new model to the report server.

In Report Builder, when I point my report to my old model, it returns some data. When I point it to the new model, however, it does not. There's no error, but it returns blank.

The report, the filters, everything is exactly the same except for the datasource which is switched back and forth.

I don't get it. Why does my data disappear when using the new model ?

Please help, I have lost many hours on this !

Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the 'explore data' in datasource view returning data?

Comment: I have modified a view - I have added a field in the view. In the Model if I click on the view and select View Sample Data, of course it returns records - after all, my view has about 5000 records right now. However, if, based on this very model, I go in the ReportBuilder and select a few fields from the model, in the QueryDesigner, my query returns nothing. If I switch to the other model, which is almost identical except for that newly added field, I have data (with the exact same query). Thank you...